# Why do Americans prefer to use the term grade instead of class?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, history, subcontinental-english, cultural-correctness

I have noticed that Americans ask kids, *Which grade are you in?*, while Indians ask, *Which class are you studying in?*

The typical Indian reply would be, say, for example, *I am a twelfth class student*, while I’m guessing that an American student would reply,  *I am currently in my twelfth grade.*

What is the difference between them? Or what is the origin of the difference between these words?  Why is there a difference in the usage of these words?

Comment: Why would one be correct and the other not correct?

Comment: Each is 'correct' (usual, customary) in the region in which it is the dominant usage.

Comment: To clarify, in Am.Eng. these questions would be about different things.  "What grade are you in?" would be answered with a number or level like 3rd Grade or Sophomore, "What class are you in?" would usually result in a teacher's name, like "Mrs. Smith's class" or "Professor Trelawney's class."  Finally, "What are you studying?" would be answered with one's major or focus, like mathematics or devination.

Comment: That's just the way it is in American English: we use 1st through 12th grades. I don't know if we ever used *class* for this. To me, the better question is whether *class* was ever used for this, or what is the origin of *grade* for this, ***not*** which usage is correct (the American English one or the Indian English one: that's like asking which is correct: *elevator* or *lift*) and not why do Americans "prefer" to use *grade*. Because we grew up using that word, we never expressed a preference for one word over another.

Comment: To make things even more confusing, a British child would find both uses uncommon, and expect "year" or even the old fashioned "form".

Comment: *Class* (and *year*) *can* be used to indicate one's education level in AmE, but are not typically for primary or middle school. What grade are you? 10th. What year are you? Sophomore. What class are you? 2020.

Comment: Do you mean a person from India or an American Indian?

Comment: A person from India.

Comment: In BrE, 'class' is the collection of students in a location. 'The whole class was seated when the teacher came in'. 'Grade' refers to an exam result. 'He achieved a low grade for arithmetic'. 'Year' refers to the academic year. 'He is in the third year at St Stevens Grammar School'.

Comment: @Nigel J: Do people in the UK use "form" in the sense of "year of advancement through primary and secondary school"? In U.S. English the standard term for this is "grade"—and we don't use "form" in this sense at all. (Hence, my lack of certainty about what exactly "fifth form" [for example] means.)

Comment: @SvenYargs A "form" can certainly be used for a cohort of students at a school, but it often consisted of two separate year groups, a lower (i.e. younger) and an upper . Precisely which age a particular form corresponded to varied somewhat by school, with the only near constant being lower and upper sixth as 17 year olds and 18 year olds respectively. Within state schools, this all officially vanished around 1990, with a switch to a system labelled form Year 1 to Year 12, corresponding to US grades. However individual names still survive in independent and public (i.e. fee paying) schools.

Comment: @SvenYargs 'Form' is unusual (in my own experience of it). I think it is only used of secondary school (age 11 to 18) and more usually only of senior forms (age 15 upwards) as you say of fifth form. 'Sixth form' used to be optional (I did it myself), beyond the legally required age for compulsory attendance, and was for pupils who already had grades in some subjects and wished to spend another year collecting extra subjects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As any dictionary will tell you, terms including *class*, *grade*, *degree*,  *rate*, *standard*, etc. share at least two separate senses: one of a stage in a sequence, another of a position in a ranking. To those who object that *grade* is a mark on a scale (*grade A*, *grade B*, etc.), the exact same could be argued of *class* (*first class*, *second class*, etc.), *level* (*level one*, *level two*, etc.), and so on and so forth. So let's leave aside what "makes sense." They *all* "make sense," but we become accustomed to certain nomenclature and so find others, well, foreign, as covered in our various and numerous discussions of other  educational terms which vary by locale, from being [in college](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66295) to [tutors and seminars](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154510) to [rising juniors](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297112) to the difference between a [diploma and a degree certificate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280847/).

According to the OED, the earliest sense of *class* as it relates to education is of *a group of students or pupils who are taught together*, attested from about 1560 onwards. In American usage attested from at least the 1670s, this meaning was extended to refer to an entire cohort of university-level students who matriculate and graduate together, a meaning still in use (e.g. *a member of the class of 2005*).

The term *grade* referred to the *grading* of schoolchildren, not in the usual modern sense of scoring for scholastic achievement or other measures of quality, but in the broader sense of sorting and grouping according to a scale, in this case age. You can *grade* in other ways that are not related to a quality standard. Crushed stone is [graded by size](https://www.braenstone.com/crushed-stone-grades/), as are coffee beans, and military and civil service ranks are known as grades, whence expressions like *[above my pay grade](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426309)* arise.

Where the grading (division/sorting) of children was done, instruction could be targeted at a particular age group, the material advancing as the children aged. This was a revolutionary idea in the era of the ungraded [one-room schoolhouse](http://www.americaslibrary.gov/es/ny/es_ny_school_1.html), and popularized as part of educational reforms in the mid-19th century [along Prussian lines](https://www.theatlantic.com/amp/article/256881/). They could have ranked them into ranks, they could have tiered them into tiers, they could have rated them into ratings, and so on, but as a matter of history they graded them into grades, and here we are.

A school large enough to organize children into classes by age was thus a ***[graded school](https://www.britannica.com/topic/graded-school)***. You can still find this term in the names of [former school buildings](http://www.opendurham.org/buildings/east-durham-graded-school-ye-smith-school) or current [school districts](https://www.rrgsd.org/), or in the occasional [old schoolbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=zJkAAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), but it became supplanted over time with ***grade school***, which further shifted in meaning to refer primarily to elementary school.

The English education system developed along very different lines from the American one, England having been settled far more densely and for far longer than anywhere in North America. Indian education in turn was heavily influenced by Victorian-era British practices, so it is unsurprising that the terminology differs, as it does in other countries with historical ties to Britain. Consider that in Canada, school years are referred to as *grades*, but with cardinal numbers— *grade five* not *fifth grade* as in the U.S.— and in Australia, they are simply *years*, e.g. *year five*.

Comment: Excellent answer—and having spent grade 11 and grade 12 in Calgary, Alberta, I can confirm your note regarding that difference in terminology between public schools there and most U.S. schools that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

According to my dictionary, in the US

a *grade* is a group of students of the same age taught together

a *class* is a group of students taught together,  but not necessarily of the same age

Comment: Indians usually refer to both as "class". In India the term grade is never used to refer to one's educational level but its used only in progress reports

Comment: Sure is a valuable answer but i think it would be more useful as to why it is different in India and the US .Sort of like its origin?